# How to hash an email from html input in Angular using Md5?

Tags: angular, hash, md5

```
import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';
console.log(Md5.hashStr('john_doe@example.com'));
```

This successfully hashes provided email outside the component but I need to implement this into Angular component?

```
export class HasherComponent implements OnInit {

    md5 = new Md5();

   constructor() { }

   hash(str: string) {
     this.md5.hashStr(str);
   }
}
```

I m not really experienced with angular yet, I have used React but never Angular and this is a problem for me. So I should call this function with passed parameter from input element:

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email:" value="" />
<button (click)="hash()">Hash it!</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the required library:

```
import {md5} from './md5';
```

And use it in the component:

```
export class HasherComponent implements OnInit {

    e: string;
    constructor() {
      this.e = md5(this.email);
    }
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Or:

```
import {Md5} from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';

export class HasherComponent implements OnInit {

    md5 = new Md5();
    hashString: string;

    constructor() {
      this.hashString = Md5.hashStr('blah blah blah')
    }
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: @AnđelkoLipotić I am glad it help. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

import {md5} from './md5'; //make sure it points to the folder where the md5.ts file is

```
let e = md5(this.email); // this.email = 'kashi_rock82@yahoo.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

import md5 in your component/service:

```
import {md5} from './md5';
```

then you can use it in your component/service:

```
let e = md5(this.email);
```